# Save user data on click button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on laravel 5.4 and I have this code:

```
  public function apply($id){
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
    $data = [
      'name' => $user->first_name,
      'family' => $user->last_name,
      'email' => $user->email,
      'username' => $user->username,
      'gender' => $user->gender,
      'birthday' => $user->birthday,
      'cv' => $user->cv,
      'about' => $user->about,
      'education' => $user->education,
      'experiences' => $user->experiences,
    ];
    $company = Company::get()->first();

    Mail::send('emails.apply', $data, function ($message) use ($company)
    {

        $message->from('noreply@gmail.com', 'Robert Nicjoo');
        $message->subject('New Apply');
        $message->to($company->email);

    });
    Mail::send('emails.uapply', $data, function ($message) use ($user)
    {

        $message->from('noreply@gmail.com', 'Robert Nicjoo');
        $message->subject('You Applied successfully');
        $message->to($user->email);

    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Your application was sent to company.');
        return redirect()->back()->with('session', $data);
  }
```

This will send email to company when user click on apply button and send user info to them, now I also want to save data of the user include `user_id, ad_id and company_id` in another table so both user and company owners can have access to their history of applied ads.

I also have this table to save data on:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('applies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('ad_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('ads', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('ad_id')->references('id')->on('ads');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('company_id')->on('ads');
        });
    }
```

but in my controller (first codes) I need to know how to save those information in new table (second codes)?

Update:

Ad Model >>

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ad extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'title', 'slug', 'image', 'description', 'address', 'job_title', 'salary',
    ];

    public function company(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
    public function category(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    public function location(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
    public function employment(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Employment::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using get()->first(), Simply use ->first(). Another thing, from where you get company_id and ad_id ?

Comment: @Sagar get()->first() has no reason just old school thing, I also updated my code as it is in my system now.

Comment: But there is no data containing ad_id ? from where you will get ?

Comment: Ok see, the button is inside `ad` (post) page which handles from another controller and the data already passed to that so when user clicks on this button it exactly knows to send email to which company `the ad owner company` so I already have those `id's` in my page maybe I can use em here or if necessary I can add it here as well. (that's my question how to get and pass the data)

Comment: can you add your route to this function ?

Comment: @Sagar `Route::get('apply/{id}', 'ApplyController@apply')->name('apply.btn');`

Comment: {id}  here refers to user_id and you are using get method instead of post method. I will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145401/discussion-between-sagar-and-robert-nicjoo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your blade is like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-round" href="{{ route('apply.btn', Auth::user()->id) }}">
```

your route should look like

```
Route::get('apply/{id}', 'ApplyController@apply')->name('apply.btn');
```

why id only ? because in the discussion we had, i found out that `ad_id` and `company_id` was taken from the controller .. then in your controller this should work

```
public function apply($id)
{
    $ad = Ad::first(); 
    $company = Company::first(); 
    $apply = new Apply(); 

    $apply->user_id = $id 
    $apply->ad_id = $ad->id; 
    $apply->company_id = $company->id; 
    $apply->save();

    // some more codes //
}
```

to avoid duplicates using user_id .. add a validation function like

```
function validateApply(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'user_id'      =>  'required|numeric|unique:apply,user_id,NULL,id,ad_id,'.$data->ad_id,
    ]);
}
```

unique:apply - it means it will check the apply table the user_id already applied ..

then in the code above just do

```
$validateApply= $this->validateApply(['user_id'=>$id,'ad_id'=>$ad->id]);
if(!$validateApply->fails())
{
    // do the above code here
}
else
{
    // duplicate !!! so do your code here
}
```

then to retrieve the data assuming apply is already belongsTo the user as well the user hasOne apply

```
Auth::user()->apply->first()->somefield;
// im not sure how the hasOne works but try
Auth::user()->apply->somefield;
```

Comment: So it actually backs to my first code except removed request and it works now thanks a lot, but 2 questions... 1- how to stop of duplicate? users only be able to apply once.  2- I cannot get results in blade.

Comment: Don't you think we should compare? eg. if we only check user id it means user only can apply in one ad and that would be all in fact user should be able to apply in as many as s(he) want just not to the same ad. i think if we compare user_id and ad_id it would be best so one user can only apply in each ad once cause will check ad_id as well. If i'm wrong please tell me

Comment: ahhh .. ok .. now i get it .. 1 ad = 1 apply per user right ? how about the company ?

Comment: yes, company doesn't matter maybe one company has 5 ads and the user want apply in all positions, but in each position only once

Comment: there you go .. updated the validation .. what we've done is avoid duplicates using user_id in that ad_id ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145408/discussion-between-robert-nicjoo-and-demonyowh).

Answer (score 0):

Your Route should be:

```
Route::post('apply/{$user_id}/{company_id}/{ad_id}','ApplyController@apply');
```

I think you have created model for ads.

So, simply save data like this:

Your function be like

```
public function apply(Request $request){

    // other code

    $apply = new Apply();
    $apply->user_id = $request->user_id; 
    $apply->ad_id = $request->ad_id;
    $apply->company_id = $request->company_id;
    $apply->save();

    // other code
}
```

And one more thing, You should have ad_id in your post request.

Comment: So you suggest I add this into my Ad model? and how exactly model will save the data? + I don't want anything saves to apply_table till user click on apply button then just get these information. for example if `ad 1` doesn't have any user apply so will no have any saves in `apply_table` I hope I explained it well!

Comment: when user clicks apply button then you have to insert data to applies and ads table am I right ?

Comment: no ads table just `applies` table. ads table is just for saving ads like posts. this info will save in `applies` table

Comment: I also added my current `Ad Model`

Comment: What's with other codes in your codes?! PS: I also have Apply model shouldn't I add this to that so will save directly in that table!

Comment: Add these codes to your apply function in controller which will save your data to applies table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145403/discussion-between-sagar-and-robert-nicjoo).

Comment: `Undefined variable: request`